# Как прикрепить патч для dll к проекту?

Tags: sdl, opengl, c++, dll

Я написал приложение на SDL + OPENGL + C++ в CodeBlocks. Обнаружил, что при запуске исполняемого файла, скомпилированного в релизе (при запуске в релизе в самой среде всё отлично работает) приложение некоторые .png файлы не загружает (а именно png-24) и выдаёт в файл для ошибок (stderr) "libpng warning: Interlace handling should be turned on when using png_ read_ image". Как выяснилось, sdl_ image использует такую libpng(а именно libpng15-15.dll, другие я пробовал, sdl_image вроде требует именно эту либу), в которой функция png_read_image имеет ошибку. Я долго искал решение (png-24 нужны), качал вроде бы более новые версии libpng, но всё тщетно. Нашёл патч, который должен фиксить эту ошибку:

```
--- libpng-1.5.0/pngread.c.ark  2011-01-14 12:27:23.440018507 +0100
+++ libpng-1.5.0/pngread.c  2011-01-14 12:28:02.866685173 +0100
@@ -841,7 +841,7 @@ png_read_image(png_structp png_ptr, png_
    }
    else
    {
-      if (!(png_ptr->transformations & PNG_INTERLACE))
+      if (png_ptr->interlaced && !(png_ptr->transformations & PNG_INTERLACE))
   {
      /* Caller called png_start_read_image or png_read_update_info without
       * first turning on the PNG_INTERLACE transform.  We can fix this here,
```

но не пойму? как его прицепить к  проекту. Скомпилировать свою libpng из исходников пока не получается (очень не хочется этим заниматься). Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: А зачем вы вообще грузите туда PNG текстуры? ETC, ATC, KTX, DDS очень много вариантов есть годной компрессии.

Comment: Мы народ не грамотный, откуда нам знать про такие форматы. Честно говоря половину впервые вижу. Просто нужен был альфа-канал и .png первое, что пришло на ум.

Comment: Эх, новички! Берете три исходные RGBA картинки приблизительно одинакового размера и одну выходную RGB, откачиваете альфа канал из каждой в выходную RGB картинку (Альфа канал 1 исходной картинки в - R выходной, Альфа канал 2 исходной картинки в - G выходной, Альфа канал 3 исходной картинки в - B выходной). Соединяете выходную картинку с альфа каналами с конвертированными в RGB 3 входными в одну большую мега RGB картинку. Пакуете в ETC формат. ETC сжимаете через ZIP еще раз. Загружаете это в OpenGL как одну большую текстуру. Просто же.

Comment: Перекомпилил, патч видимо просто убирает сообщение об ошибке, т.к. всё работает так же, только в stderr ничего не выводится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, нашёлся ответ. Собственно я нашёл решение только по другим странностям, когда релиз и дебаг версии начали работать совсем не так, как скомпилированные .ехе. начали вылетать ошибки на простейших функциях opengl и сам .ехе вариант очень тормозил. 
Оказывается я в начале сунул какую-то кривую версию библиотеки opengl в папку и компилятор работал с нормальной, а вот ехе с кривой.

Comment: Oops! Это была ошибка из серии неотлавливаемых. Хорошо, что разобрались.

Answer (score 2):

Вам придётся скомпилировать libpng.

Патч предназначен для исходников, к исходникам его и надо применять. Вы не сможете так просто применить патч исходников для бинарника.

В качестве ненадёжной альтернативы, можно попробовать дизассемблировать код libpng, найти нужную функцию, и применить патч вручную. Однако, это имеет право не сработать -- например, если оптимизатор заинлайнил кое-где вызов этой функции.

Короче говоря, легче скомпилировать.

Кстати, может быть, легче будет уговорить `sdl_image` использовать другую версию libpng?

Comment: нельзя ли как-то переопределить эту функцию из libpng, так чтобы sdl_image использовал её?
Просто в исходниках какая-то муть, там надо компилить zlib(dll его не получилось подключить) а для zlib нет каких-то ассемблерных файлов, надо качать соурсы zlib а там ещё неизвестно чего)

Comment: @Vincento Law: Может, zlib подключается как .lib?

Comment: Сейчас попробую, спасибо!

Comment: м... как его уговорить использовать другую версию? если нет libpng15-15.dll он и пишет в stderr что именно её нет, даже если есть другие. другие, какие я находил это libpng3.dll, libpng12.dll, libpng13.dll

Comment: @Vincento Law: ну, можно переименовать libpngXX в libpng15 и молиться, что всё запустится. Но вообще, лучше всё же разобраться и скомпилировать libpng, меньше геморроя.

Comment: Патч не работает. Не могу понять одного, почему когда я запускаю проект в codeblocks в release ВСЁ работает, а когда вытаскиваю exe и запускаю он не может работать с этими Png? И в debug не может.

Comment: @Vincento Law: Странно. А если запустить без IDE и подсоединиться отладчиком к процессу?

Comment: А версия и битность винды какая? Сталкивался с тем что программа прекрасно работающая из QtCreator, а также из консоли после перетачскивания к ней библиотек и запуска в консоли батника из состава Visual Studio Express тупо не запускалась сама по себе из эксплорера в винде 8 х64, когда влез в события винды - там был краш на ntdll.dll, но в явном виде об этом не сообщалось. Я пока эту проблему не решил (а если честно - и не решал т.к. это такой мелкий проект для себя который еще в процессе написания и у меня пока не было времени на это дело)